# Unable to attach database after system failures

Tags: sql, sql-server

Without going into too much detail, I had a system failure which meant that SQL got shut down unexpectedly. I have managed to detach the database and remove it from the list of databases in SSMS.

I am now trying to re-attach the database from a different location, on the same NAS;

The command I am using is this;

```
    CREATE DATABASE ArchiveManager 
ON (Filename = '\\411352-web5\m$\FTP\Detroit\ArchiveManager.mdf'),
   (Filename = '\\411352-web5\m$\FTP\Detroit\ArchiveManager_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

Originally, the database was sat on the share `j$`. I have now had to move it to `m$`.

I get the below error why trying to attach the database;

```
File activation failure. The physical file name "\\192.168.200.222\j$\FTP\Detroit\ArchiveManager_log2.ldf" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
Could not open new database 'ArchiveManager'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
```

Note that `192.168.200.222` resolves to `411352-web5`.

Comment: Is your database file on an FTP site accessed through an administrative share? What kind of permissions does the sql service use to manage that... Eeek! Have you tried a restore from backup instead of reattaching? As the error states, it appears that those files are corrupt.

Comment: Yeah everything has full permissions to see each other. I've tested it by browsing to the location from the database server. The error is pointing to the old location though, is that normal?

Comment: **READ THE ERROR MESSAGE.** What is the name of the file it specifically mentions? ArchiverManager_log2.ldf. Now look at your attach statement. See the discrepancy?